# API using MechanicalSoup is failing to submit form - NoneType

Tags: python, mechanicalsoup

I'm using a python API that uses MechanicalSoup to do most of its functions and all of a sudden, it won't work anymore. I feel like the website it's utilizing may have changed or something.

Here is the API's code:

```
def trade(self, symbol, orderType, quantity, priceType="Market", price=False, duration=Duration.good_cancel):
        """
        Executes trades on the platform. See the readme.md file
        for examples on use and inputs. Returns True if the
        trade was successful. Else an exception will be
        raised.

        client.trade("GOOG", Action.buy, 10)
        client.trade("GOOG", Action.buy, 10, "Limit", 500)
        """

        br = self.br
        trade_page = self.fetch('/simulator/trade/tradestock.aspx')
        trade_form = trade_page.soup.select("form#orderForm")[0]

        # input symbol, quantity, etc.
        trade_form.select("input#symbolTextbox")[0]["value"] = symbol
        trade_form.select("input#quantityTextbox")[0]["value"] = str(quantity)

        # input transaction type
        [option.attrs.pop("selected", "") for option in trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0]("option")]
        trade_form.select("select#transactionTypeDropDown")[0].find("option", {"value": str(orderType.value)})["selected"] = True

        # input price type
        [radio.attrs.pop("checked", "") for radio in trade_form("input", {"name": "Price"})]
        trade_form.find("input", {"name": "Price", "value": priceType})["checked"] = True

        # input duration type
        [option.attrs.pop("selected", "") for option in trade_form.select("select#durationTypeDropDown")[0]("option")]
        trade_form.select("select#durationTypeDropDown")[0].find("option", {"value": str(duration.value)})["selected"] = True

        # if a limit or stop order is made, we have to specify the price
        if price and priceType == "Limit":
            trade_form.select("input#limitPriceTextBox")[0]["value"] = str(price)

        elif price and priceType == "Stop":
            trade_form.select("input#stopPriceTextBox")[0]["value"] = str(price)

        prev_page = br.submit(trade_form, trade_page.url)
        prev_form = prev_page.soup.select("form", {"name": "simTradePreview"})
        br.submit(prev_form, prev_page.url)

        return True
```

And here is my code that I implement it with:

```
def buy(shares, ticker, client):
    client.trade(ticker,ita.Action.buy, shares)
...
if apred[0] -  arl[-1] > 0 and apred[1] - apred[0] > 0 and tickers[0] not in z:
        buy(ashr ,tickers[0], client)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carson/mlTechnicalAnalysis/investopedia.py", line 146, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 493, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 78, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 131, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 411, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
  File "/Users/carson/mlTechnicalAnalysis/investopedia.py", line 56, in main
    buy(ashr ,tickers[0], client)
  File "/Users/carson/mlTechnicalAnalysis/investopedia.py", line 16, in buy
    client.trade(ticker,ita.Action.buy, shares)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/InvestopediaApi/ita.py", line 240, in trade
    prev_form = prev_page.soup.select("form", {"name": "simTradePreview"})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1532, in select
    for candidate in _use_candidate_generator(tag):
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I've been beating my head against the wall for a few hours now and I feel like it'll take one of y'all two seconds to figure out. FYI it's an API to made trades on Investopedia's stock trading simulator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short: you're passing one too many arguments to `.select()`; you must pass a single CSS selector as a string.

Looking at the stack trace:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/InvestopediaApi/ita.py", line 240, in trade
    prev_form = prev_page.soup.select("form", {"name": "simTradePreview"})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1532, in select
    for candidate in _use_candidate_generator(tag):
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

It appears that what you pass as the second argument to `.select()` is a dict (`{"name": "simTradePreview"}`). Apparently it's not expected.

From the stacktrace it appears that the `soup` in question is BeautifulSoup 4 (`bs4`); its `select` [does not seem](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to accept a second argument. But [the source](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py#L1286) does have more undocumented arguments with default vlues, in particular, `_candidate_generator`, which you clobber.

Comment: So what is the solution? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like `'form[name="simTradePreview"]'` as a single argument for `.select()`. Knowing CSS selectors is important when working with the soup. [The docs contain numerous examples](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).